# Getting libavcodec.so.58 not found error when trying to launch retroarch on the pi 5

Tags: debian, pi, libavcodec

I recently got a raspberry pi 5 and i am running the latest 64 raspbian OS, which is based on Debian 12. I am trying to install Retroarch right now and i am using the PiKISS application. after it installed i get prompted to run it and when i press enter it gives me the error "/usr/local/bin/retroarch: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.58: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory" i am very confused and i have tried installing other applications such as steam and i get a similar issue. this is a clean install and the only things i installed before this was box64 and box86. any help would be greatly appreciated!!

i have tried researching this and while i found other people experiencing a similar issue it didnt help me fix my problem, I'm feeling very lost and im still very new to all this.